# Cakephp 3.x : Creating a new entity from within another model

Tags: entity-framework, model, associations, entity, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to build a system, where articles can have custom fields. These fields can be text or images. In the latter case, if a picture is uploaded, I would like to create a new Image entity with an entry in the database. The problem is that FieldValues is not associated with Images (since it wont always contain an image).

My plan is to do something like this:

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use App\Model\Entity\Fieldvalue;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class FieldvaluesTable extends Table
{

  ...

    function beforeMarshal($event,$data,$options){
        //Check if this is a file upload
        if(is_array($data['data']))
            if(isset($data['data']['name']) && !empty($data['data']['name'])){
                $newImage = App\Model\Table\ImagesTable::newEntity();           //This line fails
                debug($newImage);
                debug($data['data']);
            }
    }
}
```

So my question is: Is this a horrible way to go about it? And if not, how do I go about creating a new entity of an unassociated model from within this one?

Comment: Try `$newImage = TableRegistry::get('Images')->newEntity();`.

Comment: Thanks. That was the line.